# Why does my Regex match a blank line/Carriage return in Visual Studio code?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a large text file with various URLs some with and some without the http:// or https://.  I need all lines normalised to begin with https:// (or left as http:// if that is how they have been defined)

An example would be:

```
http://example.com

https://example.co.uk
www.example.org

example.co.uk
https://example.com

example.org
```

This seemed a straight forward issue to sort using Visual Code and the Regex:

```
^(?!https?:\/\/\w+)
```

and then doing a replace.  Indeed it matches correctly but also seems to match the blank lines i.e. the linefeeds.

I've tried restricting the char match in the group with `^(?!https?:\/\/[a-zA-z]+)`, but it still matches the feeds. I can replace the orphan https:// with a linefeed, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Good edits TimothyG  - Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex matches any start of a line that does not begin with `http://` or `https://` followed with one or more word chars.

You want to also exclude end of line positions, so you need to use

```
^(?!https?:\/\/\w+|$)
```

*Details*

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?!https?:\/\/\w+|$)` - a negative lookahead that matches a location that is not immediately followed with

  - `https?:\/\/\w+` -  `http://` or `https://` followed with one or more word chars
  - `|` - or
  - `$` - end of a line.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Wiktor.  I had not realised I need to implicitly match the end of the line.  I thought it would only look ahead and match exactly what I had in the group.  A lesson learned. What I do not understand is that if I use, say, ^https://, it matches ONLY those lines that begin with https:// and does not match the feeds, is it something to do with the capturing group?

Comment: @ChumKui You miss a fact that `^` does not match end of a line, it only matches the start of a line. It was not the line feeds that were matched, but only the start of any line positions.

Comment: Ah! Of course... so obvious now you mention it...  Many thanks!